# Get Context in Android Room Migration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

Get Context in Android Room Migration:

In my Migration i want to get context to read some files from assets:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object
PersistenceModule : Application() {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    ): AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "app")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_3_4)
        .build()
}
```

```
val MIGRATION_3_4 = object : Migration(3, 4) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        //...
        val txt = context.resources.assets.open("example.txt").bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class extending `Migration` which takes `context` as parameter in `constructor`

```
class Migration3to4(@ApplicationContext val context: Context): Migration(3.4) {
 override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        // access context here
        val txt = context.resources.assets.open("example.txt").bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    }
}
```

Callsite

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object
PersistenceModule : Application() {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    ): AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "app")
        .addMigrations(Migration3to4(context))
        .build()
}
```